# A riddle and a line of text

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

I have a bit of pseudocode for you, and then an encoded string. The pseudocode will help you untangle the string. It's not the most easily understood pseudocode, and that might (just might) make your task a little bit harder.

```
String[] pre to new Preamble[] with void, establish & perform:
    use package (alphabet) as al
    use package (keyboard) as qwerty
    return [answer(),getChar()]

String[] answer to new Function[] with x as parameter, perform:
    rename x to ca
    set ca to new String[]
        ~ w/ ca to al.upper[3] & al.lower[indices(3,5,19,5,18)]
    set ci to new String[]
        ~ w/ ci to al.upper[9] & al.lower[indices(13,16,15,19,19,9,2,12,5)]
    set ac to new Int[ca.length]
    set ic to new Int[ci.length]
    return ca if ac < ic else ci

Char[] getChar to new Function[] with void, perform:
    set target as new Char[]
        ~ w/ target to max(min(range(4.25*4,floor(pi**e))),0,1,2,3,-∞)
    return target

{EOF}
```

And then, the code:

> WFE3gAk2gbE3d2U3LKsngqHqgbE3fqLjd2U1CbzjfAM6LVDwOXCbfAM1

In order to receive full credit, explain the pseudocode to me and give me the answer.

## Hints

> The pseudocode is based off of Python, JavaScript, Java, and C++
> The `indices` function returns its parameters one at a time, for the purpose of its name.
> `w/` is sometimes used in texting with the same meaning....
> For the encoded string, you typically don't see these types of codes without a certain character, given by the `getChar` function.
> The `qwerty` variable contains all characters on the standard keyboard, and, for reference, this it what it would be: `["ESC","F1","F2",..."F12","INS","DEL","1","2",...,"0","-","=","BCKSPCE","\t","Q","W","E",...,"P","{","}","|","CAPS","A","S","D",...,"L"....]` - The characters are capitalized, but there are no shifted characters.
> The arrays perform on a 1-based system (i.e. $5$ would be index $3$ of $[9,30,5,2,\infty]$)

Comment: Syntax error.  `max(min(range(4.25*4,floor(pi**e)),0,1,2,3,-∞,∞/∞)`: unmatched parenthesis.

Comment: @FlorianF Thanks! I've always had trouble with the parenthesis, even in legit coding.

Comment: Does it matter what keyboard or qwerty is?  You never use them.  And I believe `indices(3,5,19,5,18)` should be `indices(1,5,19,5,18)`.  And now you have one parenthesis too much.

Comment: `max(min(range(4.25*4,floor(pi**e)),0,1,2,3,-∞,∞/∞)))` still has unbalanced parens.

Comment: Also, it currently looks like max(min(...)). Is that what you intended? Try using an editor with parentheses matching.

Comment: A couple things after the parentheses matching is dealt with: I don't see `qwerty` actually being *used* anywhere, and the ∞/∞ should probably change before the mathematically inclined guys around cringe too much.

Comment: @Scimonster I will do this when the time becomes available.

Comment: 'Standard keyboard': what country / language / layout ?

Comment: You define your function answer with a parameter an call it without parameter?

Comment: If it's relevant to the solution, it would be nice if you could post the complete contents of the `qwerty` variable, since even "standard" US keyboards differ widely in where they place the cursor control keys, the "\", etc.  If we're supposed to be working with a certain keyboard layout, we need to know exactly what it is.  (e.g. Your sample includes `INS` and `DEL`, but not `Home`, `End`, etc.  Where are those supposed to be in the array?)  Either a complete list in array format, or an actual keyboard image would be helpful.

Comment: pi**e double astreiks??

Comment: Interesting question. I hope I'm not too late to give it a try! Just curious, though: I don't do Python, JavaScript, or C++, so I wanted to ask if comparing arrays are allowed? I'm pretty sure `ac < ic` would give me an error in Java.

Comment: @mmking This is pseud-code... so, no errors, except for comprehension ones :P

Comment: OK got it. So far I have a caesar shift with key 17, on a keyboard. Am I correct so far? But then why does your code have both uppercase and lowercase characters? A keyboard doesn't have lowercase letters.

Comment: @mmking $\color{red}{\text{herring}}$

Comment: Dang it, I must have screwed it, AGAIN! :) But did I guess correctly that answer() returns "Caesar" and getChar() returns 17? And why does the end of your code say end-of-file (or somthing like that)?

Comment: @mmking Well, you've got enough to potentially answer. Try it out -- your answer need not be complete, just say it isn't. (I won't confirm anything more)

Comment: "It's not the most easily understood pseudocode" -- you've mastered the rhetorical device of understatement

Answer (score 2):

## Partial answer: interpretation of pseudocode

1. `getChar()` method:

set `target` to `max(min(range(4.25*4,floor(pi**e))),0,1,2,3,-∞)` and returns it.

$$target=max(min(range(4.25*4,floor(pi**e))),0,1,2,3,-∞)$$

$$=max(min(range(4.25*4,floor(pi^e))),0,1,2,3,-∞)$$

> ** is a python operator, meaning ^

$$=max(min(range(4.25*4,floor(22.4591577184))),0,1,2,3,-∞)$$

> floor is a math function that returns the greatest integer smaller than the input

$$=max(min(range(4.25*4,22)),0,1,2,3,-∞)$$

> $4.25*4=17$

$$=max(min(range(17,22)),0,1,2,3,-∞)$$

> range is a pythn operator that returns the set of all integers between the two inputs

$$=max(min({17,18,19,20,21,22})),0,1,2,3,-∞)$$

> minimum of the set is 17

$$=max(17,0,1,2,3,-∞)=17$$

> maximum of the numbers is 17

So `getChar()` returns 17.

2. `answer()` method:

`set ca to al.upper[3] & al.lower[indices(3,5,19,5,18)]`

> This gives `ca` = "Cceser", which is likely a misspelling of "Caesar".

`set ci to al.upper[9] & al.lower[indices(13,16,15,19,19,9,2,12,5)]`

> This gives `ci` = "Impossible".

`set ac to new Int[ca.length]`

> `ac` is set to the integer `ca.length` = 6

`set ic to new Int[ci.length]`

> `ic` is set to the integer `ci.length` = 10

`return ca if ac < ic else ci`

> `6 < 10` so `ac < ic`. Return `ca`, or "Caesar".

3. `pre()` method:

returns the result of `answer()` and `getChar()` as the preamble.

As stated before, `answer()` returns "Caesar" and `getChar()` returns 17. So `pre()` returns `["Caesar", 17]`, likely meaning a Caesar cipher with key 17.

### Some really weird things:

1. `qwerty` as defined in `pre()` is never actually used. Perhaps it means the shift is on a keyboard? Then why does the code have both capital and lowercase letters? There are only capital letters in a keyboard.
2. There is `{EOF}` at the end of the code, which likely means end-of-file. What is its significance?
3. The code has capital letters, lowercase letters, and numbers. How exactly are we going to shift?

Comment: You can't compare arrays. I used a function notation: `Int[num]` returns an integer length. (I love Red Herrings, BTW.)

Comment: I've made an edit. The code still isn't making much sense though.

Comment: Well, and it has no sense when you decrypt the code given with Caesar Cipher and key 17

Comment: @AlbertMasclans Yeah I know. I've tried several different ways, which all gave me gibberish.

Comment: It's Ccesser, not Ccessar. Also, the misspelling could possibly relate to solving the cipher.